# What about WebKit makes DOM insertion slow when your template has whitespace / text nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, dom, webkit

The following code runs slowly in the following browsers:

- Chrome 26.0.1410.65 (Mac)
- Safari 6.0.4 (Mac)

HTML:

```
<ul></ul>

<script type="text/html" id="template">
<li>
  Lorem ipsum dolor…
</li>
</script>
```

Coffeescript:

```
# Setup
list = $ 'ul'
templateText = $('#template').text()

# Append 1000 list items
list.append templateText for i in [1..1000]
```

…but if I strip the whitespace and the newlines from the template, it runs blazingly fast.

Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/cEK2x/2/

Firefox 26.0 (Mac), Chrome Canary 28.0.1500.3 (Mac), and IE9 don't exhibit this problem.

Comment: each whitespace stretch makes a new node, so the node count is a lot higher with linebreaks and space between tags than with only element nodes. i wonder if this is true for HTML layout in general; maybe HTML optimization is worth it...

Comment: You say it runs slowly in those 2 browsers. Does it run slowly in FireFox, IE, etc.?

Comment: Indeed they do form new nodes. What is it about modern WebKit that causes it to choke, whereas Firefox and Chrome Canary power right through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryosuke Niwa from the [WebKit mailing list](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-help/2013-May/003491.html) pointed me to [the bug filed in the WebKit tracker](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/144526):

> The reason is that we do not create renderers for empty text
>   nodes and thus we are hitting the worst O(N2) case in Node::attach().
>   (See FIXME in Node::attach().)
>
> This patch adds a logic to bail out the loop to avoid the O(N2) case.
>   Specifically, the patch bails out the loop if we encounter a text node
>   for which we again decided not to create a renderer. This bail out is
>   reasonable because the fact that we again decided not to create a renderer
>   for the text node indicates that there will be no affect of the result
>   of Text::textRendererIsNeeded() of the rest of the sibling nodes.